# Swift Generics where T is undeclared

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have two questions involving Generics
a) I want to do an extension function where my `Result` class in the case of `Success` accepts a Generic of type T, however, I get the following error: `Use of undeclared type 'T'`

Here's my code:

```
extension Result<T> where Success == [T] {
    /// Function extension for the .success case on a Result object. The result of the Result object are
    /// multiple object, in case a list or an iterable in being wrapped.
    /// - Parameter callback: Function that the will be executed when the .success case is triggered
    func onSuccess(callback: ([T]) -> Void) {
        switch self {
        case .success(let results):
            callback(results)
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

also regarding the same problem, I want a UIViewController to accept an array of a Generic type:
:

```
class UIObservableTableViewController: UITableViewController, LifecycleOwner {
    func addLiveData<T>(_ liveData: LiveData<T>) {
        liveDataObservers.append(liveData)
    }

    private lazy var liveDataObservers = [LiveData<T>]()
```

However, I get the same error as the previous one, how can I implement T instead of Any, or could I cast T to Any or the other way around?

I have also tried the following code:

```
extension Result where Success == Collection {
    /// Function extension for the .success case on a Result object. The result of the Result object are
    /// multiple object, in case a list or an iterable in being wrapped.
    /// - Parameter callback: Function that the will be executed when the .success case is triggered
    func onSuccess(callback: (Success) -> Void) {
        switch self {
        case .success(let results):
            callback(results)
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following compilation error: `Protocol 'Collection' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

LiveData is the following class:

```
/// Class for implementing the Observable Pattern. This is a Mutable Observable (it can change its value)
class LiveData<T> {
    private (set) var value: T

    private var valueChanged: ((T) -> Void)?

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    /// Function that sets a value on a main thread. This could throw an error is the setValue is not called inside the Main Thread
    /// - Parameter value: T object
    fileprivate func setValue(value: T) {
        print("The value is of type: \(value)")
        try! assertMainThread(methodName: "setValue")
        self.value = value
        valueChanged?(self.value)
    }

    /// Function that sets a value on a background thread. This could throw an error is the setValue is not called inside the Main Thread
    /// - Parameter value: T object
    fileprivate func postValue(value: T) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.value = value
            self.valueChanged?(self.value)
        }
    }

    /// Function that checks if the current thread is the MainThread
    private func assertMainThread(methodName: String) throws {
        if !Thread.isMainThread {
            throw CustomError("\(methodName) is not in the main thread")
        }
    }

    /// Add closure as an observer and trigger the closure imeediately if fireNow = true
    func observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, _ onChange: ((T) -> Void)?) {
        valueChanged = onChange
        onChange?(value)

        // Add the live data into its LifecycleOwner
        owner.addLiveData(self)
    }

    func removeObserver() {
        valueChanged = nil
    }
}

/// Class for implementing the Observable Pattern. This is a Mutable Observable (it can change its value)
class MutableLiveData<T>: LiveData<T> {
    override func setValue(value: T) {
        super.setValue(value: value)
    }

    override init(value: T) {
        super.init(value: value)
    }

    override func postValue(value: T) {
        super.postValue(value: value)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't instantiate an array of an unspecified generic type - When you say `[LiveData<T>]()` the compiler doesn't know *what T is* - You can use some specific generic `[LiveData<Int>]` because then the compiler knows what it is dealing with

Comment: @Paulw11 How could I initialize an array of items that could be of a generic type?

Comment: You can use `LiveData<Any>` but it is going to be ugly as you are going to have to keep casting to the appropriate type.  If you can define a protocol that encapsulates all of the properties and behaviours that you want from your observer then you could say `LiveData<SomeProtocol>`

Comment: `Success` is already a generic type. Try constraining it to the `Collection` protocol `extension Result where Success: Collection  {
    func onSuccess(callback: (Success) -> Void) {
        switch self {
        case .success(let elements):
            callback(elements)
        case .failure: return
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus it produces me the following error: ```Protocol 'Collection' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements```

Comment: The code I posted should compile. Please edit your question and show your attempt

Comment: I have edited my question with your suggestion

Comment: What is LiveData?

Comment: Your code is not what I have posted. `Collection` is not a type is a protocol `Success == Collection` is not the same as `Success: Collection`

Comment: sorry, I have updated the question with the LiveData class

Comment: Check my last comment. Your code is not what I have posted. `Collection` is not a type is a protocol `Success == Collection` is not the same as `Success: Collection`

Comment: Wow... it worked!!!... Now for the second case can I do the same thing?, can I create an array of Generic types??

Comment: Again `Success` is already a generic type

Comment: Can I do this: ```private lazy var liveDataObservers = [LiveData<T>]()```?

Comment: Why do you need to create another generic type?

Comment: For the class ```UIObservableTableViewController```, I want to remove all observers with a for loop, for that I need to create a container, like an array, and I don't know the types of what the ```LiveData```value contains

Comment: Can you break down your question with your new error? Try rewriting your question based on the code I posted

Comment: Sorry, yes, ummm the ```Result``` extension and the ```UIObservableTableViewController```class are not related, I just thought that the error where similar, now I understand why the ```Result```extension is working, however, that leaves me with the question from ```UIObservableTableViewController```, the anwer from @Paulw11 suggests me that I can't do an array of generics, is that correct, and if it do I have to make an extension for every possible Object that will be contained inside the ```LiveData```class?

Comment: `LiveData<SomeProtocol>` won't work because It will create a new generic type called `SomeProtocol`. Would be the same as `LiveData<T>` just different naming. He probably meant `LiveData<T: SomeProtocol>`

Comment: I was afraid of that!, how can I approach this issue?

Comment: If you don't break down your problem and your goal It will be hard to understand your real issue. I don't see you calling `onsuccess` anywhere in your code.